# Excel Finding the highest decimal value per integer

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a formula in Excel that returns the highest decimal value for every integer in a list.

For example, my sheet may have the values [10, 10.1,10.4, 11.3] and I need it to return both 10.4 and 11.3 since 10.4 is larger than 10 and 10.1, and 11.3 is the largest decimal value for 11.

I need this so that a pivot table can filter out the values as IDs and only return the highest value, but I can't get anything working to the point that providing my existing 'code' wouldn't help whatsoever.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is sorted, you could use the `Advanced Filter` to generate a list of the highest decimal value for each integer.

**Given:**

[image]

**Criteria Formulas:**

```
A2: =A6<>INT(A6)
B2: =OFFSET(A6,1,0)=INT(OFFSET(A6,1,0))
```

**Criteria Dialog**
*Note that you can choose to have the results copied elsewhere*

[image]

Results

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, I can't quite get the advanced filter working though. After adding the list range and the criteria range and click 'OK', it just returns the full list instead of filtering it at all.

Comment: @MaximSrour Without seeing exactly what you have done, I cannot tell what you might have done incorrectly.  It works here, as can be seen from the screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

Solve as follows:

```
value   bracket decimal
10      =int(a2)    =a2-b2
10.4    =int(a3)    =a3-b3
10.1    =int(a4)    =a4-b4
11      =int(a5)    =a5-b5
11.3    =int(a6)    =a6-b6
```

or values:

```
value   bracket decimal
10      10      0
10.4    10      0.4
10.1    10      0.1
11      11      0
11.3    11      0.3
```

Now pivot by:
bracket (columns/rows)
and in the value section add the "original value", aggregate by "max".

Comment: Hey, I have no idea what you mean in the final part of your answer. Could you please elaborate? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table and then group.

1. pivot table

[image]

2. change PivotTable Fields values to `Max of values`

[image]

3. group

[image]
[image]

4. result

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, unfortunately my sheet has too many rows and Excel gives me the "A field in your source data has more unique items that can be used in a PivotTable report." error message.