# Excel – Getting values with same integer part and highest decimal part of number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, decimal

I have list of values in A column, lets say starting from A1 cell. Lets say: `11.125, 11.5, 12.4, 12.75` .
I have huge problem how to output data in column B, but it should work like that: alghoritm of my function must choose from list only values with same integer part and maximum decimal part. So in this case i want to have in column B the following numbers: `11.5 and 12.75`, because they have highest decimal parts with same integer part.

Another example: if i have numbers:  `9.13, 9.422, 9.723, 9.04, 12.05, 13.02, 13.12, 13.42`
my function should return:
`9.723, 12.05, 13.42`

Plx HELP, because I am dying! Is it even possible to do that in excel? Maybe with Unique function?

I have tried something like this, but this not work:

```
=IF(A1="", "", IF(A1=MAX(IF(INT(A1)=INT(A$1:A$100), A$1:A$100, 0)), A1, ""))
```

Maybe somebody had similiar task and can help?
Similiar problem (i want to achieve exactly the same result) is posted here: [Excel Finding the highest decimal value per integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205772/excel-finding-the-highest-decimal-value-per-integer)

I checked first method and it does not work at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using **`Excel 2021`** as per your comments, hence the following formula should work on your end.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,D1:D8,
     b,INT(a),
     c,MOD(a,1),
     ub,UNIQUE(b),
     XLOOKUP(ub,b,SORT(CHOOSE({1,2,3},a,b,c),{1,3}),,,-1))
```

---

<kbd>LET( )</kbd> , <kbd>SORT( )</kbd> & <kbd>UNIQUE( )</kbd> function is available from **`Excel 2021`** onwards per **[MS Documentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:%7E:text=Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365%20Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365,apply%20within%20the%20scope%20of%20the%20LET%20function.)**, **[MS Documentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c)**, **[MS Documentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e)**

---

Comment: Many thanks for wide answer! Unfortunately i cannot use LET function, i am affraid its not available in MS Office Professional Plus 2021

Comment: As far I know `LET()` is available, I dont think then you are using `Excel 2021`

Comment: Do you have access to `SORT()`, `UNIQUE()` and `XLOOKUP()`? If you do it will still work: `=XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(INT(D1:D8)),INT(D1:D8),SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},D1:D8,MOD(D1:D8,1)),{1,2}),,,-1)`

Comment: Thank you very much Mayukh Bhattacharya. I am using polish version of excel and i have semicolon as separator, so I converted your code like this (assuming my data is from H8 to H15 cell): =LET(
     a;H8:H15;
     b;ZAOKR.DO.CAŁK(a);
     c;MOD(a;1);
     ub;UNIKATOWE(b);
     X.WYSZUKAJ(ub;b;SORTUJ(WYBIERZ({1;2;3};a;b;c);{1;3});;;-1))   -> unfortunately i have argument error.

Comment: Probably the array-separator. Likely you could use: `=LET( a;H8:H15; b;ZAOKR.DO.CAŁK(a); ub;UNIKATOWE(b); X.WYSZUKAJ(ub;b;SORTUJ(WYBIERZ({1\2};a;b);{1\2});;;-1))`

Comment: Guys!!! Thans for help, finally it works !!!!!!!!! WTF separator in {} should be comma (,), no matter that you use semicolon everywhere else ! Finally. OMG. Thanks P.b for giving me idea what can be wrong

Comment: @Rejnold because your settings have `,` for decimal separator, your Excel can't use that as an argument separator. Therefore Excel uses `;` as an alternative. There are horizontal and vertical separators. Where Mayukh's version has `,` for horizontal and `;` for vertical, your version uses this `;` for horizontal and likely `\` for vertical separator. You can check by typing `={1;2}` and `={1\2}` (or `={1,2\3,4}`) in a cell.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically the following will work:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=UNIQUE(XLOOKUP(INT(A1:A8)+0.999,A1:A8,A1:A8,,-1))
```

A little more verbose, but should still work for ms Excel-2021:

```
=UNIQUE(XLOOKUP(INT(A1:A8)&".*",SORT(A1:A8)&"",SORT(A1:A8),,2,-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no Excel version constraints as per your tags, you can use the following formula in a single cell. The results will spill down:

```
=DROP(
    LET(
        rg, A:A,
        int, UNIQUE(INT(rg)),
        BYROW(
            int,
            LAMBDA(arr,
                MAX(MOD(FILTER(rg, INT(rg) = arr), 1)) + arr
            )
        )
    ),
    -1
)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the answer !!!!! But unfortunately i dont have function LET in my version of excel :/

Comment: My version of excel is: MS Office Professional Plus 2021. It works brilliant on your screenshot! Thats exactly what i want to achieve!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it. See picture for reference:

```
=LET(
    a, B2:B9,
    b, UNIQUE(TRUNC(a)),
    c, DROP(
        REDUCE(
            "",
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(b)),
            LAMBDA(i,v,
                VSTACK(i, MAX(FILTER(a, INDEX(b, v, 1) = TRUNC(a))))
            )
        ),
        1
    ),
    c
)
```

[image: Picture Ref]

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Office 365 this would work:

`=SORT(UNIQUE(SCAN(0,SORT(A1:A8,,-1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(INT(a)=INT(b),a,b)))))`

[image]
*The first `SORT` is optional, to sort the result from small to large*

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for help !!!

Basically i managed to solve problem with your help.
I am operating in polish version of software and use semicolon as separator so it wasnt easy to adjust my code to your propositions/ideas. I think for me the best way to solve problem was code of Mayukh Bhattacharya, but thanks Ron Rosenfeld for fast indication of how to solve it. I couldn't find DROP function in polish so I couldn't use and test other solutions.
I give here final version of code i used (in polish MS Office Excel Professional Plus 2021):

- assuming that data is from cell H8 to H15 the code looks like following (note that sometimes you have to use comma instead of semicolon, in this kind of brackets {}):

---

```
    =X.WYSZUKAJ(UNIKATOWE(ZAOKR.DO.CAŁK(H8:H15));
 ZAOKR.DO.CAŁK(H8:H15);SORTUJ(WYBIERZ({1,2};H8:H15;MOD(H8:H15;1));{1,2});;;-1)
```